# E: Package 'xtables-addons-common' has no installation candidate

Tags: debian-buster

I'm trying to install rules to block some countries on my debian 10 server, but I find everywhere that I need to install xtables-addons-common however the package doesn't seem to exist in my debian.

When I do:

```
apt-get install xtables-addons-common libnet-cidr-lite-perl libtext-csv-xs-perl libgeoip2-perl -y
```

I get:

```
E: Package 'xtables-addons-common' has no installation candidate
```

What can I do ?

Comment: All tutorial I find to block specific countries say to install that...

Comment: Are your apt package sources correct?

Comment: I haven't changed them.

Comment: Yes that package was removed (https://tracker.debian.org/news/1033154/xtables-addons-removed-from-testing/) due to bug (https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=917905). Not sure what can be done, maybe using more recent Kernel from backports and use package pinning (https://wiki.debian.org/AptConfiguration) to pull that package from Testing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm download .deb file from [this source](https://packages.debian.org/unstable/xtables-addons-common) and install with `dpkg` command.